# Facebook access token and email address

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have a problem with facebook access token. I'm integrating iphone and facebook but am not able to receive the email address of the user. I get the access token but with it I cannot get the email. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the access token for a certain set of permissions, you can request to get the profile information of the user. Also there is a separate permission called email which you can set in your request. If the user allows your application to access that information then you can fetch the profile and parse the email successfully.

So either the email is private or you haven't requested for the permission when you fetch the access token.

Comment: Is there such a thing as "its not possible to receive the mail address" for some developers? Or can every developer receive the mail address?

Comment: I think you can get it, i request for these permissions explicitly. email,user_location,offline_access,publish_stream,read_stream,user_about_me. Its not biased towards certain developers. Why don't you try requesting for user_about_me and email and fetch the profile once you have been granted permission.

Comment: He may mean the FB user's privacy settings?

Comment: That may be possible but when you request for email the popup shows that the application may want to read email. So privacy settings may be overridden here is my gut feeling. Not sure about it though.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you are allowed to get the user's email. That's the whole point of having tokens and whatnot, to prevent security issues, regardless of the developer's intention.

Comment: What do you mean by "not allowed"? Every developer can get the mail address with the correct permission request. Isn't that right?

Comment: I was not aware of that request, my bad.